# Binding columns in GLM formula in Python

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have the following data (contraceptive use):

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_table('https://data.princeton.edu/wws509/datasets/cuse.dat',sep="\s+", header = 0)
data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 16 entries, 0 to 15
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------     --------------  ----- 
 0   age        16 non-null     object
 1   education  16 non-null     object
 2   wantsMore  16 non-null     object
 3   notUsing   16 non-null     int64 
 4   using      16 non-null     int64 
dtypes: int64(2), object(3)
memory usage: 768.0+ bytes
```

This is the data:

```
data.head()
     age education wantsMore notUsing using
1    <25       low       yes       53     6
2    <25       low        no       10     4
3    <25      high       yes      212    52
4    <25      high        no       50    10
5  25-29       low       yes       60    14
```

I want to create a model using GLM. When I use R, this is my approach, where the response (using + notUsing) depends on age, education and wantsMore:

```
lrfit = glm( cbind(using, notUsing) ~ age + education + wantsMore, data = data, family = binomial)
```

In this case I require to bind the cols in the formula. But for python I have tried this:

```
model = sm.formula.glm("notUsing + using ~ C(age,education,wantsMore)", family=sm.families.Binomial(), data=data).fit()
```

But there is an error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'code_without_intercept'`, I guess it's because of the binding of notUsing and using. Please, could you help me with this formula?

Comment: `"using + notUsing ~ age + education + wantsMore"` should work

Comment: See https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/discrete_choice_example.html?highlight=binomial#Aside:-Binomial-distribution for an example.

Comment: The 'object' dtypes may be causing issues.